# Move main content over header photo

Tags: css

Design question here. How can I make the #main-wrapper slide over the #single-carousel on the following page: http://duijnisveld.wpengine.com/

Right now it moves up when scrolling, I need the carousel to stay put and make the main wrapper slide over it when scrolling down.

giving `.header-foto-wrapper` `position: fixed` and `#main-wrapper` `position: relative` gives unexpected behaviour for me, I'm clearly missing something important.

*note, in the url, the `.header-foto-wrapper` does not have the position fixed as it breaks the layout and it's a live site for the client to see.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: sorry, I added some things I tried and did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to apply width. Things go a little wonky when a container calculates width once you pull it out of the content flow. A width:100% will fill the page width. You'll also want to move the content area down and apply a background color.

```
.header-foto-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. I was so close, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By setting the position as absolute.

```
.wrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 150px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: everytime I add `absolute` or `fixed` to the `.header-foto-wrapper`, the headerphoto disappears....